# Why I do not get all the valuenya when in for loop

Tags: javascript

I want to get the value of these two hidden inputs.

Why do I get unsuitable results?

```js
$('button').click(function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var DATA_IMAGE = $('.wrap-img-attachment input[type="hidden"]').val();
  COUNT_IMAGE = $('.wrap-img-attachment input[type="hidden"]').length;

  for (var i = 0; i < COUNT_IMAGE; i++) {
    $('#result').html(DATA_IMAGE[i]);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK THIS</button>
<div class="wrap-img-attachment absolute-top-right trns-03s">
  <input type="hidden" value="Hello">
  <input type="hidden" value="World">
</div>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Please for the senior correction :)

Comment: `DATA_IMAGE` is the value of the *first* such input. That aside, even if you were getting the values correctly, you'd only see the last one because you keep overwriting the output area.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, 
Is there any other method